# How to get month written in full for URL access date?

Tags: biblatex

In my example below, I would like to change the appearance of the URL access date. Rather than the date being typed numerically like

> (accessed 2013-09-01).

I would like the month to be written in full and displayed like this

> (accessed 01 September 2013).

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,maxcitenames = 2,mincitenames = 1,maxbibnames = 99,minbibnames = 1,dashed = false,firstinits=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}  
% !BIB TS-program = biber     
%^ line above is necessary to tell TeXShop to use Biblatex rathern than traditional BibTex.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    % utf8 support       
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}       % code for pdf file  % w/out these two lines, I get the warning, "WARN - The entry '_______' has characters which cannot be encoded in 'ascii'. Recoding problematic characters into macros.

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{Test.bib}    
@unpublished{usgs_gmted_data,
Author = {{United States Geological Survey}},
Title = {USGS Global Multi-resolution Terrain Elevation Data (GMTED) product},
Url = {http://topotools.cr.usgs.gov/gmted_viewer/},
urldate = {2013-09-01}, 
urlmonth = {September},                    % Added                                
Year = {2010}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{Test.bib}

% Add the text, "Available at:" prior to URL and "accessed" afterward in parentheses.
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%          
urlseen = {accessed}
}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
urlseen = {accessed},
url = {Available at:}
}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{url}\space\url{#1}}

% Prevent Italics for booktitle in these data types 
\DeclareFieldFormat
[article,book,manual,misc,software,unpublished]
{booktitle}{#1}

 % Remove quotations around the following titles.
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,book,collection,incollection,manual,misc,
periodical,proceedings,report,thesis,software,unpublished]{title}{#1} 

%% =================================================
\begin{document}
Test cite \parencite{usgs_gmted_data}.

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The citation looks like this:

> United States Geological Survey (2010) USGS Global Multi-resolution Terrain Elevation Data (GMTED) product. Available at: http://topotools.cr.usgs.gov/gmted_viewer/ (accessed 09/01/2013).

But I'd like it to look like this:

> United States Geological Survey (2010) USGS Global Multi-resolution Terrain Elevation Data (GMTED) product. Available at: http://topotools.cr.usgs.gov/gmted_viewer/ (accessed 01 September 2013).

Comment: Have you tried  with the option `urldate=long`, i.e., `\usepackage[...,urldate=long,...]{biblatex}`

Comment: @ Guido, you're suggestion is close to what I want. It shows `(accessed Sept. 1, 2013)`.  When I alter my .bib file to include the field `urlmonth = {September}`, your suggestion prints `(accessed September 1, 2013)`, which is almost exactly what I want.

Comment: Add  the `dateabbrev=false` option.

Comment: Adding `dateabbrev=false` doesn't alter it. If I remove the `urldate=long` while keeping `dateabbrev=false`, it prints out this, `(accessed September/01/2013)`.

Comment: In the bibtex record,  the value of  `month` you should use either a number or a 3-letter abbreviation

Comment: Except a number or 3-letter abbreviation don't fit the journal's requirements. I need it to be `(accessed 01 September 2013)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apart from `urldate=long` and `dateabbrev=false` option, you need some bibliography extras similar to those for `australian` language, but you needn't to strip leading zeroes from numbers.

So, you can add the following lines to your preamble (code taken and modified from `australian.lbx`):

```
\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \protected\def\mkbibdatelong#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\thefield{#3}%
       \iffieldundef{#2}{}{\nobreakspace}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}}%
    \iffieldbibstring{#1}{\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}{\stripzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
}
```

Note that you don't have the need to write specific `urlmonth` and `urlday` in your `.bib` file.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,
            maxcitenames = 2,
            mincitenames = 1,
            maxbibnames = 99,
            minbibnames = 1,
            dashed = false,
            firstinits=true,
            urldate=long,
            dateabbrev=false,
            backend=biber]{biblatex}

% !BIB TS-program = biber
%^ line above is necessary to tell TeXShop to use Biblatex rathern than traditional BibTex.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    % utf8 support
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}       % code for pdf file  % w/out these two lines, I get the warning, "WARN - The entry '_______' has characters which cannot be encoded in 'ascii'. Recoding problematic characters into macros.

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{Test.bib}
@unpublished{usgs_gmted_data,
Author = {{United States Geological Survey}},
Title = {USGS Global Multi-resolution Terrain Elevation Data (GMTED) product},
Url = {http://topotools.cr.usgs.gov/gmted_viewer/},
urldate = {2013-09-01},
Year = {2010}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{Test.bib}

% Add the text, "Available at:" prior to URL and "accessed" afterward in parentheses.
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
urlseen = {accessed}
}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
urlseen = {accessed},
url = {Available at:}
}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{url}\space\url{#1}}

% Prevent Italics for booktitle in these data types
\DeclareFieldFormat
[article,book,manual,misc,software,unpublished]
{booktitle}{#1}

 % Remove quotations around the following titles.
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,book,collection,incollection,manual,misc,
periodical,proceedings,report,thesis,software,unpublished]{title}{#1}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \protected\def\mkbibdatelong#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\thefield{#3}%
       \iffieldundef{#2}{}{\nobreakspace}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}}%
    \iffieldbibstring{#1}{\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}{\stripzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
}

%% =================================================
\begin{document}
Test cite \parencite{usgs_gmted_data}.

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Very helpful and I appreciate the clarification regarding what's necessary in the .bib file.

Comment: @user76245 You're welcome.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to replace `\thefield{#3}` with `\stripzeros{\thefield{#3}}` since 1 July 2018 looks better than 01 July 2018.

Answer (score 4):

The format of the `urldate` is controlled by the `urldate` options, for a long date, use the `long` option. The second option to set is whether abbreviations are used, i.e., `dateabbrev=false`.

Finally, to achieve the British date format, one has to set `language=british`.

With the above options, i.e.,:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear,
  maxcitenames = 2,
  mincitenames = 1,
  maxbibnames = 99,
  minbibnames = 1,
  dashed =false,
  firstinits=true,
  backend=biber,
  urldate=long,
  dateabbrev=false,
  language=british]{biblatex}
```

the MWE provided  in the OP produces:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to alter `1st` to `01`? In my .bib file, I tried `urlday = {{01}}`, but it prints `010th` rather than what I hoped / need.